SVG line chart using d3 is not rendering to full height along y-axis
I am rendering a svg line chart using d3. For y axis the maximum value in chart data is 104 and minimum is 0. I have taken height of chart to 500. But the maximum value i.e 104 should be rendered at top height but its rendering at height somewhere near height of 270.
Also how can I get y value of svg path from x position inside svg bounds?
I am using timestamps for x axis values in chart data
My Code:
import * as shape from "d3-shape";
import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
const SIZE = 500
const data = [
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1723939200000 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1724284800000 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1724371200000 },
    { "weight": 60, "date": 1724493742250 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1724544000000 },
    { "weight": 104, "date": 1724653305251 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1724716800000 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1724803200000 },
    { "weight": 0, "date": 1725235200000 }]

const formattedValues = data.map((rec) => [rec.weight, rec.date] as [number, number]);
const weights = formattedValues.map((value) => value[0]);
const dates = formattedValues.map((value) => value[1]);
const scaleX = scaleLinear().domain([Math.min(...dates), Math.max(...dates)]).range([0, SIZE]);
const minWeight = Math.min(...weights);
const maxWeight = Math.max(...weights);
const scaleY = scaleLinear().domain([maxWeight, minWeight]).range([0, SIZE])
const path = shape.line().x(([, x]) => scaleX(x) as number).y(([y]) => {
    return scaleY(y) as number
}).curve(shape.curveBasis)(formattedValues) as string

export function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="homeContainer">
            <svg 
                height={SIZE} width={SIZE} fill="yellow" style={{ border: '2px solid blue' }}>
                <path
                    d={path}
                    stroke="black"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                />
            </svg>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home

blue border is svg width and height and this is how chart renders

Remember that width and height need units because they tell the parent document how to size the SVG. You can't just pass it the number 500, it needs to be 500 "somethings" (e.g. width={`${SIZE}px`}). And on a react note: don't add divs that you don't need, React is notorious for "div hell" where everything's divs in divs in divs: use Fragments (or the short code <>....</>) if you need to group multiple elements, but in this case you don't: just return the svg element.

(Of course none of that solves your problem, for that you'll probably want to show an [mcve], which this isn't quite yet)

I think its because I am using shape.curveBasis which smooths out the curve btween the points of data, somehow it dampens the original values. I tried using other curves for ex. shape.curveBumpX then the max weight value correctly maps at the height of SVG.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
